# Configuring CodeNarc in Gradle

Tags: plugins, configuration, gradle, codenarc

I am trying to wrap my head around using [CodeNarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/index.html) inside of [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/codenarc_plugin.html).

According to the CodeNarc docs, my project needs to have a `config/codenarc/codenarc.xml` config file defined. But then I see plenty of example config files (such as [this StarterRuleSet](https://codenarc.org/StarterRuleSet-AllRulesByCategory.groovy.txt)) that seem to use a Groovy DSL.

So I ask:

1. Is it possible to use a Groovy DSL, and if so what does the name of the file have to be, where does it have to be located in my project, and how do I wire it up to my Gradle build?; and
2. Where is the documentation on the Groovy DSL?; and
3. By default, CodeNarc outputs a report called `main.html`; how could I change the name of this file to, say, `codenarc.html`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like in your `build.gradle` you can just put:

```
codenarc {
    toolVersion = "0.20"
}

codenarcMain {
    configFile = rootProject.file("path/to/CodeNarcMain.groovy")
}

codenarcTest {
    configFile = rootProject.file("path/to/CodeNarcTest.groovy")
}
```

Where the file names (`CodeNarcMain`, `CodeNarcTest`) are whatever you want them to be.

[Groovy DSL documentation is here.](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-creating-ruleset.html#Creating_a_Groovy_RuleSet_File) If you need to configure a specific rule, look it up in the documentation and if the rule has public properties that it exposes, they'll be listed in a table under the specific rule's documentation.

And it looks like you can only [change the report file format](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CodeNarcExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CodeNarcExtension:reportFormat) (HTML, XML, text, console) but not the actual file name produced.

Comment: I'm guessing they broke this at some point, because I can't get the current version of the plugin to recognise codenarcMain as a valid method.

Comment: Where do you get the "0.20"?  And, you're right, it does, but unfortunately substituting 3.3.0 (the latest) for your "0.20" doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Hakanai You're right.  I've noticed the same with 3.3.0.